# sklearn's PCA inversion, dimension error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, pca

Trying to understand the sklearn.decomposition.PCA API and it's giving me a hard time.
I divided my data (40features x 10 samples) into training (39 samples) and testing subsets (1 sample).

I commented the code with what ***I think/ guess*** is happening.

```
X_train, X_test = X_all[ix1], X_all[ix2]

# Instantiate PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=n_comps)

# train the model
X_train_reduced = pca.fit_transform(X_train)

# reduce X_test
X_test_reduced = pca.transform(X_test)

# invert X_test back to original number of components
X_test_inv = pca.inverse_transform(X_test)  # <--- ERROR

....
[this would continue with checking errors bassed on n_comps]
```

Error on the indicated line states the following:
shapes (1,40) and (n_comps,40) not aligned: 40 (dim 1) != n_comps (dim 0)

**EDIT**:
Dimensions of the variables:
`X_test = 1 x 40`
`X_train = 9 x 40`
`X_test_reduced = 9 x n_comps`

How should this **actually** be done?

Comment: `X_test` is the original data, you cannot inverse that.  You should do `pca.inverse_transform(X_test_reduced)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here is that you are trying to apply `pca.inverse_transform` to your original data. The purpose of this function is to take as input the principal components and transform it back to the data. Here you are passing as input the data instead.

From the docs:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.inverse_transform

You see that for `pca.inverse_transform` the input should be `X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_components)` which in your case is `(1, 10)` and that's why you get this error

I guess what you 'd like to do is

```
X_test_inversed = pca.inverse_transform(X_test_reduced)
```